# iOS Local Notification Interval

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm scheduling a series of several local notifications that would ideally fire as soon as possible in quick succession.  Basically, the user needs to be notified of new data downloaded from a background fetch.

Based on some tests I've run, it seems like iOS doesn't respond well to fire dates of a second or two from the current date, and it doesn't like notifications that are scheduled either at the same time or quite close to one another.

Can anyone comment on this?  Is it possible to schedule multiple local notifications for immediate/near immediate display in quick succession?